# Attribute -webkit-box-orient in css not working when build in vuejs?

Tags: css, vue.js, build, production

I use attribute -webkit-box-orient normal when local. But when i build to web by npm run build, then attribute not working and appear in devtools. How to apply this attribute?

I have tried:

```
.ellipsis {
    /* autoprefixer: ignore next */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and

```
.ellipsis {
    /* autoprefixer: off */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    /* autoprefixer: on */
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

but when build, similar situation happened?

Anyone recommend solution for me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a hard one. My friend found this page https://blog.csdn.net/niesiyuan000/article/details/79301492

```
/*! autoprefixer: off */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  /* autoprefixer: on */
```

seems to do the trick, if you don't want to change the configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try :D but if not, what file i must config?

Comment: The blog linked to in the answer has some ideas. You might need to translate it.